# How to print the list of args and kwargs

Tags: python, formatting, keyword-argument

In my code, I have many places where I pass a function and its arguments to another function. For debugging purposes, I want to print the name of the function and the list of arguments. For example

```
def process(f, *args, **kwargs):
    print("processing " + print_func(f, args, kwargs))
```

The expected output for 
    `process(myfunc, 1,2, a="A",b=0)` should be `"processing myfunc(1,2,a="A", b=0)"`

I made some progress printing the `args` as follows:

```
def print_func(f, *args, **kwarg):
    func_str = f.__name__ + "("
    if len(args) > 0:
        func_str = func_str + (', '.join(['%.2f']*len(x)) % args)
     func_str = func_str + ")"
```

which in the example above will produce the output `processing myfunc(1,2)`

The problem I have is how to print the kwargs. I can't figure out a similar solution using a dynamic formatting string for printing it as a sequence of `k=v` pairs separated by ",".

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To format `args` and `kwargs`, you can simply iterate over them and create your string representation

```
def process(my_func, *args, **kwargs):

    #Iterate over all args, convert them to str, and join them
    args_str = ','.join(map(str,args))

    #Iterater over all kwargs, convert them into k=v and join them
    kwargs_str = ','.join('{}={}'.format(k,v) for k,v in kwargs.items())

    #Or using f-strings
    #kwargs_str = ','.join(f'{k}={v}' for k,v in kwargs.items()

    #Form the final representation by adding func name
    return "processing {}({})".format(my_func.__name__, ','.join([args_str,kwargs_str]))

    #Or using f-strings
    #return f"processing {my_func.__name__}({','.join([args_str,kwargs_str])})"

print(process(my_func, 1,2, a="A",b=0))
```

The output will be

```
processing my_func(1,2,a=A,b=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by creating an annotation like this

```py
def printArgs(my_func):
    def wrapper(*arg, **kwargs):
        print("{}({})".format(my_func.__name__, ','.join([str(arg),str(kwargs)])))
        return my_func(*arg, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@printArgs
def a_function_where_you_want_to_print_args(arg1, arg2, arg3="arg3"):
    pass

a_function_where_you_want_to_print_args(1,2, arg3="b")
```

This will print "a_function_where_you_want_to_print_args((1, 2),{'arg3': 'b'})"

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but for legibility I would prefer to print the function parameter list a (1,2, argg=b). As I mentioned, I managed to do so with args but not kwargs.

Comment: I don't understand why this answer was downvoted, since it would be powerful for debugging if it could be applied on any function in your code just by adding a decorator. But there's one detail I am missing: the code inside the function would not work? (I replaced `pass` with `print('Inside a_function_where_you_want_to_print_args')` but it doesn't get printed out)

Comment: I got my answer from a decorator tutorial: you need to call the function you are passing to the decorator from the decorator itself before returning the wrapper. In this case calling `my_func(*arg, **kwargs)` before `return wrapper` would do. Again, beautiful solution.